# Createfile in path given by user only if the file doesn't exist

Tags: c#, file, directory

I'm trying to create a file only if the files doesn't exist in the path located and that the directory i guess path exists too and if the file already exist I don't let the user continue so the app closes. I tried doing this but it seems that when I give the location it tells me the file exists when it doesnt.

```
this.path = @output;
      this.path2File = @output + "\\" + type + "tobearchived.txt";

if (!Directory.Exists(path) && !File.Exists(path2File))
      {
        File.Create(path2File);
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: File Already Exists. Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Environment.Exit(0);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IF condition seems faulty, try following;

```
  if (Directory.Exists(path) && File.Exists(path2File))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: File Already Exists. Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
   File.Create(path2File);
  }
```

**Edit:** The problem in your code is, Let's say that directory exists but file doesn't. Then '!Directory.Exists(path)' is 'false' and it will skip checking for 'File.Exists(path2File)' because of **AND** condition.
Therefore, control will directly go to 'else' part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked fine for me.

```
 FileInfo Finfo;
 public bool StartLog(string path)
 {
      Finfo = new FileInfo(path);
      if (Finfo.Exists)
      {
          Finfo.Delete();
          FileWriter = Finfo.AppendText();                   
      }
      else
      {              
          FileStream fs = Finfo.Create();
          fs.Close();
          FileWriter = Finfo.AppendText();
      }
 }
```